# Doing IFFT and saving back to wavfile doesn't work

Tags: python, audio, fft, wav, ifft

I have the following function where I'm trying to do FFT on a audio file and reset the phases and putting it all back together as a new audio file. First I do the FFT on both channels and then normalize the amplitudes. When I'm trying to do the final matrix from which to save the audio file it says:

> ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional

even though it is 2-dimensional. Also I'm getting this warning:

> ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary
>   part   arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

I'm not sure if my approach to deal with amplitudes and phases is the best anyway so I'd appreciate any tips how to get my code working.

```
import scipy.fftpack as fft
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hanning
import math



def readNormalize(location):

    samplerate, data = wavfile.read(location)

    leftChan = data.T[0] # first track of audio
    rightChan = data.T[1]

    length = len(leftChan)
    fftLeft = fft.fft(leftChan[0:], length)
    fftRight = fft.fft(rightChan[0:], length)

    #length is half(positive frequency) of the the fft data, because other half is negative (complex conjugate)
    length = int(length/2)

    #getting the normalization value
    ownSum = 0;
    for i in range(0, length):
        ownSum += abs(fftLeft[i])
    normalizer = 1/ownSum

    amplitudesRight = []
    phasesRight = []

    phasesLeft = []
    amplitudesLeft = []

    #normalizing and setting the phases
    for i in range(0,length):
        #LEFT CHAN
        amplitudesLeft.append((abs(fftLeft[i])*normalizer))
        phasesLeft.append(0)
        #RIGHT CHAN
        amplitudesRight.append((abs(fftRight[i])*normalizer))
        phasesRight.append((math.pi/2))

        #TRIED THIS ASWELL BUT CAN'T APPEND LIKE THIS
        #fftLeft[i] = (abs(fftLeft[i])*normalizer)
        #fftLeft[i][i] = 0

        #fftRight[i] = (abs(fftRight[i])*normalizer)
        #fftRight[i][i] = math.pi/2


    #putting the phases and amps back to complex form(at least trying)
    matrixLeft = np.matrix([amplitudesLeft, phasesLeft], dtype=np.complex128)
    matrixRight = np.matrix([amplitudesRight, phasesRight], dtype=np.complex128)

    #ifft for the complex
    ifftLeft = fft.ifft(matrixLeft)
    ifftRight = fft.ifft(matrixRight)

    #putting all the data back together, 
    #doesn't work, says that matrix has to be 2-dimensional
    outputMatrix = np.matrix([ifftLeft, ifftRight],dtype=np.int16)

    wavfile.write('test.wav',samplerate, outputMatrix)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: >If the data type of x is real, a “real FFT” algorithm is automatically used

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what yo mean, can you clarify it a little bit? Like where I'm doing the mistake?

Comment: And also if somebody can suggest a better way to manipulate phases and amplitudes I'd be happy to hear. My solution seems to involve quite many steps and ending up with many arrays so I feel there is probably a lot effective way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: sorry, confusing numpy's fft with scipy fftpack, I'd use `np.fft.rfft` `irfft`.  Then you only have to modify phase of the 1st N/2 frequencies and not worry about reversing and conjugating.  FFT phase is best modified by multiplying each frequency complex point/bin by `np.exp(1j*d_phase)` where `d_phase` is the radian phase shift you want to apply at each frequency

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that! Does the rfft accept stereo or do I have to have the channels separated? Also if I want to set all the phases to to some specific values can i do np.exp(0j) or np.exp((math.pi/2)j)? I'm trying to recreate an algorithm used by this one sound artist where left channel is set to 90 degree phase and right channel 0 degree.